# Cannot determine why function of a program returns an array to the main program

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, return

I am having difficulty in understanding why a string that was concatenated in a function outside of main was able to be printed out in the main function. In short, this program was designed to illustrate the concatenation of two char arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concat(char result[], const char str1[], int n1, const char str2[], int n2)
{
    int i, j;

    // copy str1 to result
    for (i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = str1[i];
    }
    // copy str2 to result
    for (j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
    {
        result[n1 + j] = str2[j];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    void concat(char result[], const char str1[], int n1, const char str2[], int n2);
    const char s1[5] = { 'T', 'e', 's', 't', ' ' };
    const char s2[6] = { 'w', 'o', 'r', 'k', 's', '.' };
    char s3[11];
    int i;

    concat(s3, s1, 5, s2, 6);

    for (i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        printf("%c", s3[i]);    // Here is what I do not understand: how was the s3 array
                                // accessible since it was not returned from concat
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

As I understand, unless a function returns a value OR the array/variable is globally declared (which is something one should try to avoid: we want a tight scope) then the array/variable should NOT be 'visible' to the main?  Is this not correct? Because I thought the s3 would need to be returned from the function to be used by the main to print it out.

Comment: This program was an example from 'Programming in C' by S.Kochan.

Comment: You're passing the address of the array `s3[]` to `concat`. So `concat` can't change `s3` since it's not within its scope, but it can certainly change what `s3` points to, which is the array contents.

Comment: See, the thing is - you're not actually passing the data in the arrays to the function, but rather, a pointer to the start of the array. The `const` keyword before str1 and str2 merely tells the compiler to prevent you from modifying them. (and are more-or-less irrelevant - I just thought it worth a mention)

Comment: Passing by reference like this allows you to use helper methods to do some repeatable stuff to the object(s) without having that in the calling method's code. When the called method completes, your object has been updated. You'll use it all the time in any Object Oriented language.

Comment: mbratch, what I still do not grasp, is that the change to s3 occurred withing the 'concat' function, so why is it that the change, which I understood ONLY existed within the scope of the 'concat' function, was accessible to the main function. From what you are saying, the main is changing what s3 points to, but what it points to took place inside of a function out of the main scope. If 'concat' returned the s3 values to main, that would have made sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in C use pass by value for paramenters.  When you pass s3 as the first argument of concat, you are passing the value, 'address of the array s3'.  The function concat uses the address as the location of the argument you named result.  The function copies values into the memory location result (which is another name for s3 in the calling function).

When the function reaches the end of the function concat, the array at s3 has been modified.

To illustrate this, print out the address of s3 before calling concat,

```
printf("s3 address: %x\n",s3);
```

And then print out the address of result inside concat,

```
printf("result address: %x\n",result);
```

The value you are passing as s3 is the address of s3[], which is a reference to the char[11] memory buffer.

Comment: Saved me again, Mr. Cottrill. Your coding wisdom is saving me from an early aneurism. Thank you for clearing that up. So to reiterate, once main shoots a value to a function, that is in this case an address to an array, the function may change the sent array, albeit in parameter form, and this change does indeed affect the array in the main (since the changes is pertaining to addresses). This  in -function change will not work with variables though:
void mod(int a)
{
a = a + 1;
}
int main(void)
{
void mod(int a); 
int num = 5; 
printf("%d\n",num); 
mod(num);
printf("%d",num); 
return 0; 
}

Comment: When you pass an (char,short,int,long,float,double) variable, you are passing by value.  If you want to change one of these non-pointer values, you would need to pass the address.

Comment: Suppose you have a variable, int x, and you want to pass the address to a function, that is spelled, &x.  The function would have a corresponding parameter, func(int* xp), and you change the value of x (at address xp) using the dereference operator, spelled, *xp = 4;

Answer (score 1):

A value in an array can be accessed and modified anywhere that the array is visible.  In this case, you are altering your array inside of your "concat" method.  The array is a reference to these values, so while you are not returning this new array, when you change the elements of the array they are changed everywhere that the array is referenced from.

Answer (score 0):

actually,your program is gets output bye a output parameter concept. I am supposed to write a void function called Result that has only three type int input/output parameters. The function will return the sum of the two original parameters through the first parameter. . I don't know if I am doing this right,but i don't know is this helps to you?

02

```
#include <stdlib.h>
03  #include <stdio.h>
04   
05  void result(int *sum, int a,int b);
06   
07  int
08  main(void)
09  {
10            int  num1, num2,sum=0;
11              
12             /* Gets test data */
13             printf("Enter the first number");
14             scanf("%d", &num1);
15             printf("Enter the second number");
16             scanf("%d", &num2);
17             result(&sum,num2, num1)           
18              
19             printf("The first number is %2.d", num1);
20             printf("The second number is %2.d", num2);
21             system("pause");
22             return (0);
23             }
24  void
25  result(int *psum, int *num1,int num2)
26  {
         sum=a+b;
27   }
36                                  
37
```